# PySpark + jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trynig to configure a spark context into my notebook, but there is something wrong, I do :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

if sc==sc:
    sc.stop()
if spark==spark:
    spark.stop()

conf = SparkConf()
conf = conf.setAppName(appName)
conf = conf.set("spark.master", master)
conf = conf.set("spark.python.worker.memory", "1042M")

spark.stop()
session_builder = SparkSession.builder
session_builder = session_builder.master(master)
spark           = session_builder.getOrCreate()
```

and this give me an error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.
```

Can we change the configuration of spark in a jupyter notebook ? 
And how ?

I am on the last version of spark with a standalone cluster.

Following the propose action I did : 
[image]
which seems to mean the spark Context has been recreated, but the sparSession is not linked to the new sc anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `config` option when setting SparkSession (as of 2.4)

```
MAX_MEMORY = "5g"

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Foo") \
    .config("spark.executor.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
    .config("spark.driver.memory", MAX_MEMORY) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code above, what I understand is `sc` is you sparkcontext and `spark` is your sparkSession variable. You are stopping both of them and then using spark.stop() again on an already terminated session. Instead use this:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc.stop()

conf = (SparkConf()
         .setMaster("local")
         .setAppName("App_name")
         .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"))
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

You can find the documentation here: [Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/python-programming-guide.html)

If you have configured your notebook with pyspark, you don't need to stop a spark context and create a new one. Instead you can you `sc` as you spark context. You can pass additional configurations via spark-submit as command line arguments. You can refer the configuration documentation here:[Pyspark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

Comment: ok, it kind of work, but how to update the sparkSession ? I update my question on this point

Comment: my question is precisely : is it possible to update the sc configuration on the fly into a notebook ?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change the configuration dynamically or on the fly in the notebook. You need to stop the running context, and create a new with your desired configuration.

Comment: If your spark version is 2.0.0 or above, you don't need a spark context. Spark session would suffice. If you continue using spark context, you'll have to create separate contexts for using sql or Hive API's which you don't need to incase of spark session. You can directly access API's using your spark session variable .

You can refer this link here: [DataBricks Spark session and Spark context](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/08/15/how-to-use-sparksession-in-apache-spark-2-0.html)